# React Native Android app Crashing again and again

Tags: react-native, crash, google-play-console

I have made a react native app and published it on the Google Play Store. But when it was published it was crashing again and again and the logo was also changed a bit. Before the publishing, it worked fine. Please help me out.

Here's the link for the app:

***https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shubham_deswal.lblood_app***

Comment: Did you check all of the environmental variables? Maybe something on production is set for debug.

Comment: Please update the question by adding your apps build.gradle file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also faced this kind of issue
and the following command worked for me

1. Run Following command

   react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
2. Manifest.xml

   <application
   android:name=".MainApplication"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" // add this line with TRUE Value.
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
3. Permission

   On your Mac, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click Privacy. Select Files and Folders. Select the tickbox below an app to allow it to access files and folders in that location. Deselect the tickbox to turn off access for that app.

Comment: Sorry but I am not using Android Studio. I am using react native or node.

Comment: I use this step but app crash aging and aging app properly run in my device but not run other device so what can I do

Comment: Can you please check the versions of those phones ?

Comment: @ShubhamDeswal you can run this command in vs code

Answer (score 0):

if you are here from React Native way...

try running

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

it will update your app's index.android.bundle which is actually the whole app, due to some reason some changes are not getting reflected in the bundle and when you run the above line it will update the index.android.bundle and you will be having updated code base inside it.

Also some extra resources will get generated because of this, you need to remove them after the app runs because next time it will cause you duplicate asset issue.